# Converting Python Dict to Sparse RDD or DF in PySpark

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have some code that I prototyped in Pandas that I'm attempting to convert to PySpark code. It uses the `urlparse` Python library to parse a generic URI to a Python dict, convert the keys to new columns, then concatenate those new columns back with the original data. A simplified example is below. In the real dataset there are 38 columns, and I care about keeping all of them.

```
# create some sample data
df_ex = pd.DataFrame([[102,'text1',u'/some/website/page.json?ovpevu&colc=1452802104103&si=569800363b029b74&rev=v4.1.2-wp&jsl=161&ln=en&pc=men&dp=www.mysite.com&qfq=news/this-is-an-article&of=2&uf=1&pd=0&irt=0&md=0&ct=1&tct=0&abt=0&lt=792&cdn=1&lnlc=gb&tl=c=141,m=433,i=476,xm=1243,xp=1254&pi=2&&rb=0&gen=100&callback=_ate.track.hsr&mk=some,key,words,about,the,article&'],
          [781,'text2',u'/libtrc/hearst-network/loader.js'],
          [9001,'text3',u'/image/view/-/36996720/highRes/2/-/maxh/150/maxw/150/mypic.jpg'],
          [121,'text4',u'/website/page2.json?ovpevu&colc=1452802104103&si=569800363b029b74&rev=v4.1.2-wp&qqd=1&pd=0&irt=0&md=0&zzct=1&tct=0&abt=0&lt=792&cdn=0&lnlc=gb&tl=c=414,m=32,i=41,xm=1000,xp=111&callback=_ate.track.hsr&mk=some,other,key,words,about,the,article&'],
          [781,'text5',u'/libtrc/hearst-network/loader.js']],columns=['num','text','uri'])

# parse the URI to a dict using urlparse
df_ex['uri_dict'] = df_ex['uri'].apply(lambda x: dict(urlparse.parse_qsl(urlparse.urlsplit(x).query)))

# convert the parsed dict to a series
df_ex_uridict_series = df_ex['uri_dict'].apply(pd.Series)

# concatenate the parsed dict (now columns) back with original DF
df_final = pd.concat([df_ex, df_ex_uridict_series], axis=1).drop('uri_dict', axis=1)
```

Resulting in something that looks like this (cropped):

[image: Result after parsing URI; Pandas DF (sparse matrix)]

The result is quite sparse, but that's fine. For the application, I actually prefer it to be a sparse matrix of sorts (although I could be convinced if there's a good alternative, dense approach). And it's this result that I'm attempting to recreate in PySpark.

Where I've got to thus far is (in PySpark 2.1.0) this (using the same data).

```
# urlparse library
import urlparse

# create the sample data as RDD
data = sc.parallelize([[102,'text1',u'/some/website/page.json?ovpevu&colc=1452802104103&si=569800363b029b74&rev=v4.1.2-wp&jsl=161&ln=en&pc=men&dp=www.mysite.com&qfq=news/this-is-an-article&of=2&uf=1&pd=0&irt=0&md=0&ct=1&tct=0&abt=0&lt=792&cdn=1&lnlc=gb&tl=c=141,m=433,i=476,xm=1243,xp=1254&pi=2&&rb=0&gen=100&callback=_ate.track.hsr&mk=some,key,words,about,the,article&'],[781,'text2',u'/libtrc/hearst-network/loader.js'],[9001,'text3',u'/image/view/-/36996720/highRes/2/-/maxh/150/maxw/150/mypic.jpg'],[121,'text4',u'/website/page2.json?ovpevu&colc=1452802104103&si=569800363b029b74&rev=v4.1.2-wp&qqd=1&pd=0&irt=0&md=0&zzct=1&tct=0&abt=0&lt=792&cdn=0&lnlc=gb&tl=c=414,m=32,i=41,xm=1000,xp=111&callback=_ate.track.hsr&mk=some,other,key,words,about,the,article&'],[781,'text5',u'/libtrc/hearst-network/loader.js']])

# simple map to parse the uri
uri_parsed = data.map(list).map(lambda x: [x[0],x[1],urlparse.parse_qs(urlparse.urlsplit(x[2]).query)])
```

This gets me fairly close, with a python dict nested inside each "row" of the RDD. Like this:

```
In [187]: uri_parsed.take(3)
Out[187]:
[[102,
  'text1',
  {u'abt': [u'0'],
   u'callback': [u'_ate.track.hsr'],
   u'cdn': [u'1'],
   u'colc': [u'1452802104103'],
   u'ct': [u'1'],
   u'dp': [u'www.mysite.com'],
   u'gen': [u'100'],
   u'irt': [u'0'],
   u'jsl': [u'161'],
   u'ln': [u'en'],
   u'lnlc': [u'gb'],
   u'lt': [u'792'],
   u'md': [u'0'],
   u'mk': [u'some,key,words,about,the,article'],
   u'of': [u'2'],
   u'pc': [u'men'],
   u'pd': [u'0'],
   u'pi': [u'2'],
   u'qfq': [u'news/this-is-an-article'],
   u'rb': [u'0'],
   u'rev': [u'v4.1.2-wp'],
   u'si': [u'569800363b029b74'],
   u'tct': [u'0'],
   u'tl': [u'c=141,m=433,i=476,xm=1243,xp=1254'],
   u'uf': [u'1']}],
 [781, 'text2', {}],
 [9001, 'text3', {}]]
```

The values contain lists, but that's fine. They can just stay as lists.

What I'd like to do at this point is parse out the key/value pairs from the dict (like in Pandas) to create new columns from the keys and then place the value (or list of values, in this case) in the RDD.

Some things I've tried:

- Going full-blown PySpark DF: wrote a UDF and applied using `with_column` to create a new column in the DF. This works, but it gives me the entire dict as a single string (without the keys and values being in quotes). I didn't attempt to push forward on this and add the quotes (figured there was a better way).
- Splitting the original DF: first assign a unique ID to each DF row using `monotonically_increasing_id()`, split out two columns (the new ID and the URI), converting the split to a RDD, then parsing. This will let me then join back (using the ID), but it didn't help with creating the "sparse matrix" that I want.

It also occurred to me that these technologies (using Spark v2.1.0 with a Hive datastore) may not be the correct underlying technology to represent this type of data. Perhaps a schema-less datastore would be better. However, I'm constrained right now to use Spark and Hive as the datastore.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was recently looking at a similar problem parsing strings containing key value pairs separated by '=', where the possible keys weren't known beforehand.

I'm not sure that it's the most efficient solution, but I came up with a solution that runs through the rdd a few times to discover and deal with the arbitrary tags.

First, parse out the URLs and num-text pairs that label the rows:

```
def urlparsefn(url):
    return urlparse.parse_qs(urlparse.urlsplit(url).query)

# parse the uri to a dictionary
uri_parsed = data.map(lambda x: (x[0],x[1],urlparsefn(x[2])))
```

Then you can extract all the distinct tags by extracting the unique keys of each uri dictionary, then aggregating them together using the Python `set`, which lets you remove easily remove duplicates.

```
# We need to discover all the unique keys before we will know which columns our data frame will have
combOp = (lambda x, y: x.union(y))
possible_keys_set = uri_parsed.map(lambda x: set(x[2].keys())).aggregate(set(), combOp, combOp)
possible_keys = sorted(list(possible_keys_set)) # sets have no order, this will give us alphabetical order in the final dataframe
```

Now that we have all the unique possible keys, we can extract the distinct num and text that label the row, and then make sure each dictionary has all the tags in it, using some placeholder text for elements that don't exist in the particular uri dictionary. Then you can build an rdd of Rows using the keyword arguments in Python.

```
def attrmap(urirow, possible_keys):
    # Extract the 3 parts of the uri tuple
    num = urirow[0]
    text = urirow[1]
    uridict = urirow[2]

    # Assign the known fields identifying the row
    uridict['num'] = num
    uridict['text'] = text

    # Run through the possible keys, add a placeholder for any keys not present in the row
    for key in possible_keys:
        if key not in uridict:
            uridict[key] = 'N/A' # Some place holder for values in the list of possible keys, but not in the current uri dictionary
        else:
            uridict[key] = uridict[key][0] # All the lists only have 1 item, so just extract the item

    return uridict

# Create an rdd of Row type, using the dictionary as kwargs
uri_allkeys = uri_parsed.map(lambda x: Row(**attrmap(x, possible_keys)))
```

Then the last thing is to build out the schema for the new dataframe based on the num, text, and all the extracted possible columns.

```
# Create an item in the schema for the known fields, and each possible key
df_schema = StructType()
for possible_key in ['num','text']+possible_keys:
    df_schema.add(possible_key, StringType(), True)

# Use the new schema and rdd of rows to create the dataframe
uri_parsed_df = spark.createDataFrame(uri_allkeys, df_schema)
```

This should give the dataframe with arbitrary columns. Hope this helps!